# Fedora 18, grub2 reinstall, /mnt is empty

Tags: fedora, livecd, grub2

I have a common problem. I installed Fedora 18 on a PC that also has Windows on it. When I start the PC, I don't get asked which system I want to boot; Windows is chosen always.

So I found out that I have to reinstall grub2. So I booted from the Live CD and entered rescue mode (hit `e` in grub2 and adding `single` to the line that begins with "linux.."). Then I should do `chroot /mnt/sysimage`, but there is no such directory; when I do `cd mnt` and `ls`, it's empty. So I have no idea how to change root. When I do `fdisk -l`, the Fedora installation is in partition `/dev/mapper/fedora-root`.

I am totally lost. All help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora live CD is one thing, but your installation on the hard drive is another one.

First boot from LiveCD, terminal, as su -

```
fdisk -l
mount /dev/sdaQ /mnt
```

where Q is your partition where the `/grub2` directory is located.

> `grub2-install --boot-directory=/mnt/grub2 /dev/sda`
>                                                   !! check that `sda` is really the target drive !!

This is what `/mnt/grub2/grub.cfg` contains ...

```
menuentry "Memtest86+-4.20" {
    linux16 /memtest86+-4.20
}

menuentry "android DEBUG" {
    set root='(hd0,msdos6)'
    linux /android-2012-07-17/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=desktop_generic acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode SRC=/android-2012-07-17 DEBUG=1
    initrd /android-2012-07-17/initrd.img
}

menuentry "windows" {
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry 'Fedora Linux, with Linux 3.6.11-4.fc16.x86_64' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='(/dev/sdc,msdos1)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d67ef75d-d8ac-409e-a6ca-f2bbdde2569e
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.6.11-4.fc16.x86_64 ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.6.11-4.fc16.x86_64 root=UUID=ef32401f-6579-4894-9e02-918fed37657d ro rd.md=0 rd.lvm=0 rd.dm=0  KEYTABLE=us quiet SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rhgb rd.luks=0 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initramfs-3.6.11-4.fc16.x86_64.img
}
```

Comment: this is what grub.cfg contains or should contain?

Comment: I did you grub2-install, nothing changed, still booting windows only